# How do you prevent a uiwebview from caching a web page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a web view that loads a url on request. However, when this web view reloads the same url, the content does not get updated, but remains as it was after it was first loaded. I'm assuming this is due to automatic caching? Deleting the apps documents and data allows the webview to be refreshed, but then the issue occurs again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting NSURLRequest's cachePolicy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData.

Comment: Champion! Works like a charm.

Comment: Thats weird because if you look at the header for NSURLRequest NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData remains unimplemented!

Answer (score 1):

From NSURLRequest.h iOS 8.0

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSURLRequestCachePolicy)
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
```

you should be using NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData. I had the same problem. I relied on autocomplete and used the unimplemented methods.